# Insert n Items in a Gridlayout responsively

Tags: android-gridlayout

I want to insert a variable number of ImageButtons into a Gridlayout.

(1) My first Idea would be doing this repetition in xml like

```
<GridLayout>
  <RepeatNTimes n="@/class/property">
    <ImageButton \>
  </RepeatNTimes>
</GridLayout>
```

But I don't know such a Tag.

(2) The next Idea would be to use a separate xml-File for the ImageButtons. This does not work easily, because they need Grid-Layout-Specific attributes.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
   android:id="@+id/xmlgrid"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   app:columnCount="2">
```

Necessary parameters for ImageButton.

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  app:layout_columnWeight="1"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_peg_2" />
```

(3) Another Idea would be to insert everything programmatically, which is certainly not the most elegant way. But I did not get the Parameters working correctly

```
ImageButton b = new ImageButton(getContext());
b.setImageResource(Const.BLACK_PEG);
b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
b.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
b.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
// Layout Params
GridLayout.LayoutParams p = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
p.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f);
b.setLayoutParams(p);
xmlgrid.addView(b);
```

[Wrong position when adding button programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L56K.png)